# How use EntityManager from typeorm inside an entity nest.js

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to make a query in a typeorm entity class in nest.js

```
@Entity()  
export class EntityName {
  constructor(@InjectEntityManager() private readonly entityManager: EntityManager) {}

  //(...)

  @BeforeInsert()
  async someFunction() {
     await this.entityManager.query(`
       Some sql sentence         
     `) 
  }
}
```

I use EntityManager in a service as well and give me no problem, but in the entity give me undefined. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Using EntityManager you can manage (insert, update, delete, load, etc.) any entity. EntityManager is just like a collection of all entity repositories in a single place.

So, why are you using entity manager in entity class?

Comment: @NairiAbgaryan i need to make a query to restart to alter a sequence under a condition. I used getManager(), but its deprecated, so i'm looking for a better solution